# Electrons on multiple levels of energy

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, physics

I was asked to find the number of posibilities to find $6$ electrons in $8$ levels of energy, without restrictions, I was intuiting that this problem is totally equivalent to put $n$ balls in $k$ boxes, so in order to calculate I use

\begin{equation}
\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}
\end{equation}
where $n$ is the number of balls (electrons) and $k$ is the number of boxes (energy levels). So with this, I found that exists 3432 possibilities to put the electrons in those levels. There is no restriction about empty levels.

Is this even right?

Comment: electrons are fermions, no two electrons can share same quantum state. So each energy level can hold at most 2 electrons (factor 2 from the internal spin degree of freedom).

Comment: I agree with that, fermions follow Pauli's principle, but the problem was questioned assuming that the principle does not exists, just for mental analysis.

Comment: It depends on who asks this question. If this is asked in a math classes which have no idea what electron is, then your interpretation is correct. if this is asked in a physics or chem classes, then the Pauli exclusion principle will be implicitly assumed and each energy level can hold at most two electrons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strategy is correct, but your answer has an extra factor of $2$.

Since there are six electrons to be distributed to eight levels of energy, we want the number of solutions of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 + x_8 = 6$$
in the nonnegative integers, where $x_i$, $1 \leq i \leq 8$, is the number of electrons in the $i$th energy level.  A particular solution corresponds to the placement of seven addition signs in a row of six ones.  For instance,
$$1 1 1 + 1 1 + 1 + + + + +$$
which corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 3$, $x_2 = 2$, $x_3 = 1$, $x_4 = x_5 = x_6 = x_7 = x_8 = 0$.  The number of such solutions is the number of ways we can place seven addition signs in a row of six ones, which is 
$$\binom{6 + 8 - 1}{8 - 1} = \binom{13}{7} = 1716$$